# Enumerable Func with different return types

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it possible to have an Enumerable Func with different return types, I think the answer is no but how could one support this. My code currently looks like this but I need to be able to pass different return types as input types and vs versa. I want to have a structure where the previous actions return type forms the input to the next action.

- action 1 takes A and returns B
- action 2 takes B and returns C
- action 3 takes C and returns D

Im building something of a virtual machine that takes test instructions but I am a bit unsure how to progress from here.

The code below is how I would ideally like it to work but it obviously wont ... any thoughts on the best approach?

```
IEnumerable<Func<Tariff, Tariff> actions = new Func<Tariff, Tariff>[]
{
   a = > {CreateStandardTariff();}, //returns typeof(StandardTariff)
   a = > {CreateTariff();}          //returns typeof(Tariff) takes StandardTariff      
};

Test(actions);
```

...

```
public void Test<T>(IEnumerable<Func<T,T>> actions) where T : class
{
      T current = null;
      foreach(Func<T,T> action in actions)
         current = action(current);
}
```

I am using 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a common interface or abstract base class between the input and output types. e.g. `ITariff`

```
class Tariff : ITariff {}
class StandardTariff : ITariff {}
```

and then use:

```
Func<ITariff, ITariff>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **dynamic** or **object** as the input and output types